# Java json object replace keys names

Tags: java, json, loops, key

I have Json like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5e99f6d16cbddf7dad26557f"),
"channel_id" : 49066,
"timestamp" : NumberLong(1580982302003),
"values" : {
    "some id" : "81151501",
    "some title" : "Some title",
    "some address" : "https://www.some-address.com",
    "new hash" : {
        "some value" : "5",
        "other value" : " 54.10 BRL"
    },
    "wrong values" : "This text have wrong & values & and netx is wrong too & and this &"
},
"null value" : null,
"zero integer" : 0
}
```

I need to loop through each key and replace spaces with snake_case, for example from `other value` to `other_value`

Additionally, I wanted to check every value in the loop by replacing the character `&` with `_`, for example:

from `This text have wrong & values & and netx is wrong too & and this &` to `This text have wrong _ values _ and netx is wrong too _ and this _`

My json object is made from:

```
JSONobject jsonObject = new JSONobject(jsonString)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the keys, normalize the key and recursively continue as long as the value is a JSONObject. If it's not, then you could normalize the value as well. So this would look something like this:

```
static JSONObject normalize(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
    Iterator iterator = object.keys();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = (String) iterator.next();
        String normalizedKey = key.replace(" ", "_");

        Object inner = object.get(key);

        if (inner instanceof JSONObject) {
            result.put(normalizedKey, normalize((JSONObject) inner));
        } else if (inner instanceof String) {
            result.put(normalizedKey, object.getString(key).replace("&", "_"));
        } else {
            result.put(normalizedKey, inner);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Latest version of the library also provides the ability to obtain a keyset, which would allow for a slightly cleaner looping of the keys:

```
static JSONObject normalized(JSONObject object) {
    JSONObject result = new JSONObject();

    object.keySet().forEach(key -> {
        String normalizedKey = key.replace(" ", "_");
        Object value = object.get(key);

        if (value instanceof JSONObject) {
            result.put(normalizedKey, normalized((JSONObject) value));
        } else if (value instanceof String) {
            result.put(normalizedKey, ((String) value).replace("&", "_"));
        } else {
            result.put(normalizedKey, value);   
        }
    });     
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank You VOX, but if one of the key values are null, I get org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["key_name"] not a string.

Comment: Did it happen with the same example? In that case, we could be using different versions of the library.

Comment: Yes for null or integer key values I get org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["key"] not a string.

Comment: Looks like we had different version of org.json. I updated the initial example and added another one which makes use of the key set that is also provided with the latest version of the library.

Comment: Now it's working ;) Thank You VOX. How did you know that this could be a problem with the library version?

Comment: Cool. The previous solution was working for me with the same input so version mismatch seemed to make sense.

Comment: @vox this does not rename if the object has array inside.